# Dynamically compute value from multiple FormControl valueChanges with rxjs in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-formbuilder

I have an array of `FormGroup`s which all holds one `FormControl` called `checked` which is represented as a checkbox input in the template.

This array `formGroups$` is computed from another `Observable` called `items$`.

```js
// component.ts
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  items$ = of([{ whatever: 'not used' }, { something: 'doesnt matter' }]);

  // doesn't work!
  formGroups$: Observable<FormGroup<{ checked: FormControl<boolean> }>[]> =
    this.items$.pipe(
      map((items) => {
        const array: FormGroup[] = [];
        for (const item of items) {
          const formGroup = this.fb.group({});
          formGroup.addControl('checked', new FormControl(false));
          array.push(formGroup);
        }
        return array;
      })
    );

  allChecked$: Observable<boolean> = this.formGroups$.pipe(
    switchMap((formGroups) => {
      const valueChangesArray: Observable<boolean>[] = [];
      formGroups.forEach((formGroup) => {
        valueChangesArray.push(
          formGroup
            .get('checked')
            .valueChanges.pipe(startWith(formGroup.get('checked').value))
        );
      });
      return combineLatest(valueChangesArray);
    }),
    map((checkedValues) => {
      console.log(checkedValues);
      for (const isChecked of checkedValues) {
        if (!isChecked) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    })
  );
```

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<ng-container *ngFor="let formGroup of formGroups$ | async; index as i">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="formGroup.controls.checked" />
    {{ i }}
  </label>
</ng-container>

<p>allChecked: {{ allChecked$ | async }}</p>
```

Example see also in Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xfpywy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Now when I try to compute if all those checkboxes are checked with `allChecked$`, which combines all Observables from each `FormGroup`s `formControl.valueChanges`, the `map` in there only gets triggered once and not as expected every time the value of a Checkbox changes:

[image]

If I change `formGroup$` to a simpler static solution, the value `allChecked$` is computed correctly every time:

```js
  // works!
  formGroups$: Observable<FormGroup<{ checked: FormControl<boolean> }>[]> = of([
    new FormGroup({
      checked: new FormControl(false),
    }),
    new FormGroup({
      checked: new FormControl(true),
    }),
  ]);
```

You can easily reproduce it in this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xfpywy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

How do I compute this boolean `allChecked$` with an array of dynamically created `FormGroup`s?

Answer (score 1):

*Update 03, december*

Yes, as @akoted comment, really you have **two** different arrays of formGroups!!

We can check if we declare a variable

```
forms:any[]=[]
```

and write

```
formGroups$ =
    this.items$.pipe(
      ...
    ,
    tap(res=>{
        this.forms[this.forms.length]=res
    })
```

Then use `{{forms[0]==forms[1]}}` in .html.

One solution can be use SharedReply

```
formGroups$ =
    this.items$.pipe(
      ...
    ,
    sharedReply(1)
)
```

Another one is use "tap" operator to create the allChecked$ Observable

```
  allChecked$: Observable<boolean>;
  formGroups$: Observable<FormGroup<{ checked: FormControl<boolean> }>[]> =
    this.items$.pipe(
      map((items) => {
        const array: FormGroup[] = [];
        for (const item of items) {
          const formGroup = this.fb.group({});
          formGroup.addControl('checked', new FormControl(false));
          array.push(formGroup);
        }
        return array;
      }),
      tap((formGroups: any[]) => {           //here we create the Observable
                  //see that "formGroups" are your array of FormGroups

        const valueChangesArray: Observable<boolean>[] = [];
        formGroups.forEach((formGroup) => {
          valueChangesArray.push(
            formGroup
              .get('checked')
              .valueChanges.pipe(startWith(formGroup.get('checked').value))
          );
        });
        this.allChecked$ = combineLatest(valueChangesArray).pipe(
          map((checkedValues) => {
            for (const isChecked of checkedValues) {
              if (!isChecked) {
                return false;
              }
            }
            return true;
          })
        );
      })
    );
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-teyebd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Where exactly do I have two different arrays of FormGroups? I only have `formGroups$` defined once...
Also, how would I use `shareReplay` in this example?

Comment: @jones1008, my Bad! your'e correct, Now I feel that is the same formGrop[]. I'll try to understand why not work and revised my answer :(

Comment: @Eliseo you were right. He has two different `FormGroup[]`. The `formGroups$` async subscription has a different instance than the `allChecked$` async sub. // btw in the random$ test you've made in your stackblitz, you are getting the same number cause the `Math.random` doesn`t get executed for each subscription. If you use `defer(() => of(Math.random()))` instead you'll see that you get a different number for each sub.

Comment: @akotech, Yes, they are different array, we can check it, e.g. we create an array forms, and adding a tap`this.forms[this.forms.length]=res`, then we check if this.forms[0]==this.forms[1]. We can also use formGroups[0].pacthValue({checked:true})` and we can see that they are dirrecnets, Thanks by your comment